# Promise or Future in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've started to learn FP and recently i read 'Mostly adequate guide to FP'. In chapter about Functors author says that it's good to use 'Task (Future)' structure instead of Promise beacuse it's not pure. So it's confusing me cause they are both impure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Can you rephrase that so there's a clear question?

Comment: My understanding is that the terms _task_, _future_, and _promise_ all fundamentally refer to the same design concept, but different implementations and capabilities.

Comment: A *task* often is (a data structure that reprsents) a function that can be executed and returns a promise (also called future there). The execution of that function would always be impure though.

Comment: Okay, but why author recommends to use Task instead of Promise?